# How can I associate variables with each other?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, web-scraping

I am beginning to write code in order to do some datavis using data from wikipedia tables.

Having just about managed to produce a bar chart using plotly express, I'm now struggling conceptually.

The way I have been instructed to do this is to read in two separate columns-of-interest from the wikipedia tables (In my case this would be (i) Country Names (ii) Rates of Alcoholism), and then create a dictionary like this:

```
dictionary = {'Countries':countrynames,'Score':floatal}
```

And then use this to plot.

Where I am struggling conceptually is that this method is reading in the columns and just plotting them by index (i.e. the method is assuming that the indexing of the columns stays in tact e.g. `CountryNames[3]` still corresponds to `RatesOfAlcoholism[3]` as it did in the original table.

Would it not be better practice to be associating these values as individual key:value pairs so that the variables can be manipulated/processed without screwing up the indexing?

I find I am now just stuck with a dictionary of values that I can't manipulate or sort, for fear of messing up the order.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you aware that since Python 3.7 the *Dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion order.*? And you can sort dictionaries and manipulate them too!

Comment: Okay that helps my understanding quite a bit - thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two iterables with similarly-indexed data that work as key value pairs, CountryNames and RatesOfAlcoholism, just use a dictionary comprehension to combine them:

```
dictionary = {CountryNames[i]: RatesOfAlcoholism[i] for i in range(len(CountryNames))}
```

This will give you the key value pairs you desire.